# Composer Package (PHPLeague) in Codeigniter loading class

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I am aiming to use the following package for my project [Color Extractor](https://github.com/thephpleague/color-extractor).

I have composer working and setup in my project fine as per @philsturgeon's tutorial [here](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2012/05/composer-with-codeigniter/), however I am stuck as the function returns an empty array for an image I know is there.

I am autoloading in the index.php using `require FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';`

And I have tested this using Phil's example.

My Code looks like this:

```
    $client = new League\ColorExtractor\Client();
    $image = $client->loadJpeg(FCPATH.'assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o1_250.jpg');

    // Get the most used color hex code
    $palette = $image->extract();

    // Get three most used color hex code
    $palette = $image->extract(3);

    // Change the Minimum Color Ratio (0 - 1)
    // Default: 0
    $image->setMinColorRatio(1);
    $palette = $image->extract();

    var_dump($palette);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here as I don't have any errors in my log and I get the standard output.

> array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

I was being utterly stupid apologies for anyone who viewed this question I was trying to declare multiple variables with the same name and variants of the function.

My final code looks like

```
    $client = new League\ColorExtractor\Client();
    $image = $client->loadJpeg(FCPATH.'assets/images/tumblr_ma7gmzwfAq1r780z3o1_250.jpg');
    $palette = $image->extract(3);
    var_dump($palette);
```

Which returns an expected array like this.

> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "#E09D73" [1]=> string(7) "#AC4C34" [2]=>
>   string(7) "#EEDF6C" }